# CSS: how to hide part of a tag's content?

Tags: css

I have no control of the following markup:

```
<p class="filename">
    <img src="http://domain.com/uploads/image_gallery/_thumbs/Chrysanthemum.jpg" alt="Chrysanthemum.jpg">
    <br>
    Chrysanthemum.jpg
</p>
```

I would like to do hide from display the `<br> Chrysanthemum.jpg` part. Is this possible in CSS?

Comment: well, the first step would be to put that part seperately into a different tag (probably a `div`, in that case you could also get rid of the `br`, killing two birds with one stone)

Comment: I think OP wants to hide <br> Chrysanthemum.jpg.   Can jQuery of JS be used?

Comment: oh, sorry, i see you can't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp):

```
p.filename {
  visibility: hidden;
}

p.filename img {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/UVEZIsUN/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Using Visibility still keeps the space occupied by the hidden elements, even though they are not visible but they will still take up the same space as before.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job for you:

```
p.filename {
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
}

p br {
    display:none;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mx74U/